# Losing autofus on Vue.js toggle of v-show

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, vue.js

Strange, the autofocus attribute of my inputs don't work when I am changing the element being displayed

See the fiddle attached: https://jsfiddle.net/e53Lgnnb/6/

Code: 
HTML:

```
<body>
<!-- Email [POST] -->
<div class="" id="email" v-show="activeStep == 'email'">
    <form action="onboarding-5.html" @submit.prevent="submitForm('email', 'password')">
        <div class="form-row">
            <input type="email" autofocus required placeholder="email">
        </div>
        <p>
            <button type="submit" class="button">Ok <i class="icon arrow-right"></i></button>
        </p>
    </form>
</div>

<!-- Password [POST] -->
<div class="onboarding-content-wrap" id="password" v-show="activeStep == 'password'">
    <form action="onboarding-6.html">
        <div class="form-row">
            <input type="password" autofocus required placeholder="password">
        </div>
        <p>
            <button type="submit" class="button">Ok <i class="icon arrow-right"></i></button>
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
    new Vue({
    el: 'body',

    data: {
        activeStep: 'email',
    },

    methods: {

        // Show the step as active
        getNextStep: function (nextStep) {
            this.activeStep = nextStep;
        },

        submitForm: function (currentStep, nextStep) {
            this.getNextStep(nextStep);
            console.log(response.data);
        }
    }
});
```

What's going on?
Thanks a lot !

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if 'autofocus' tag is only processed one – when the initial DOM is loaded. Hence, a solution with watch (see answer below) seems very reasonable

Answer (score 1):

Autofocus only works on `page load`. If you want to change the focus when the user submit the form, I suggest you to create a watch for "activeStep".

Something like this

```
watch:{
    activeStep(step){
        if( step === 'email'){
            this.$els.emailField.focus();
        }
        // ...
    }
},
```

More info:

> The autofocus content attribute allows the author to indicate that a
> control is to be focused as soon as the page is loaded, allowing the
> user to just start typing without having to manually focus the main
> control.
>
> There must not be two elements with the same nearest ancestor
> autofocus scoping root element that both have the autofocus attribute
> specified.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fe-autofocus

Answer (score 1):

Check this jsfiddle

> jsfiddle.net/blogui91/e53Lgnnb/12/

i just create a new component which shows the input, but with the difference when is created, it focuses automatically depending of the prop 'autofocus' the same for if it's required. and a prop called 'model' it will help you the update the value in the parent component using '.sync' to update it, I hope it helps you

Comment: I like that. I stripped it down to $('input').focus() on ready because there is just one per screen :-)

Answer (score 0):

Temporary work around until I understand exactly why it can't work. Add:

```
watch: {
        activeStep: function () {
          $("#" + this.activeStep + " input[name=" + this.activeStep + "]").focus();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you make the password field a `v-if` rather than a `v-show`? You'll always be on the password step when the form gets submitted, so you don't have to worry about the field not existing when it's submitted.  Because `v-if` creates the dom element only when it's true, the `autofocus` attribute would trigger as it is created.

Comment: So I tried but then it makes me lose the  data-parsley validation for some reason...